# Binding second type parameter through reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Is there a way to create a generic type with unbound first parameter but with bound second parameter? More specifically, I need to call `Queryable.Where<T>(IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)` and don't know how to distinguish between overloads, one of which takes `Expression<Func<T, int, bool>>`

Comment: There's only one type parameter in both methods. Do you just want to find the right overload by reflection?

Comment: Please provide more context - are you actually trying to write a type, or a method? What is this meant to achieve? Your tag suggests you're trying to call the method via reflection, but there's nothing mentioned in the question about that. With reflection you can easily distinguish between the overloads by looking at the parameter types...

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm trying to find a correct overload by directly comparing parameter type to the type I need. At the moment I dig deeper than I want to by using something like this `mi.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType.GenericTypeArguments[0].GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Func<,>);`

Comment: Well that's pretty much what you should be doing... and that information should be in the question.